# Regular expression to find money value

Tags: java, regex

I have response text:

```
Cuoc no truoc -2.134VND. Cuoc phat sinh tam tinh den 31/08/2018:
3`2.666VND (da tru KM,goi cuoc...). TKFastpay: 0VND.Tra 01.Trang sau 02.Thoat\",15
```

i want get result is value of money before `"VND" -> -2.134` and `32.666` and `0`.

I have regex

```
String regex = "(?<![^=])([\\d]*)(?!$[VND])";
```

but its not work.
Please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead `(?=` and a word boundary after VND `\b`.

`-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=VND\b)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C6PrYe/1)

That would match

- `-?` Optional minus sign (To also allow a plus, you could use an optional character class `[+-]?`
- `\d+` Match one or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` An optional non capturing group matching a dot and one or more digits
- `(?=VND\b)` Positive lookahead that asserts what is on the right is `VND`

In Java:

`-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?=VND\\b)`

[Demo Java](http://rextester.com/NPVO19126)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i have new issue. It not work with number : -5.127.030VND -> it will return only 127.030 . I fixed regex into [+-]?(\d+\.?\d+\.?\d*)(?=VND\b) probem solved but it can regconize 0NVD. You can see here : https://regex101.com/r/HtgVEC/4

Comment: @HoangNam Instead of using an optional part using the questionmark `(?:\.\d+)?` you could repeat that part zero or more times using the asterix `(?:\.\d+)*`. Your regex would look like [`-?\d+(?:\.\d+)*(?=VND\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/J2hT8M/1/). In Java `String regex = "-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)*(?=VND\\b)";`

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex with a lookahead:

```
[+-]?\d+\.?\d*(?=VND)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HtgVEC/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `[+-]?`: Match optional `+` or `-`
- `\d+\.?\d*`: Match a floating point number or integer number
- `(?=VND)`: Assert that we have `VND` at next position

**Java Code:**

```
final String regex = "[+-]?\\d+\\.?\\d*(?=VND)";
final String string = "Cuoc no truoc -2.134VND. Cuoc phat sinh tam tinh den 31/08/2018:\n"
+ "32.666VND (da tru KM,goi cuoc...). TKFastpay: 0VND.Tra 01.Trang sau 02.Thoat\\\",15";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the requirement, then the regex, used in a repeated fashion, might be:

```
(-?)[\\d][\\d.]*(?=VND)
```

The idea being that you need at least one digit, followed by more digits or a decimal, then followed by VND.

A slightly improved approach would be to split the [.] to be between the digits, so:
    ((-?)[\d]+[.]?[\d]*)(?=VND)

[Online Example](https://regex101.com/r/GLmKPS/1)

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

```
String regex = "(-?[0-9]+[\.]+[0-9]*)VND"
```

### Description:

1. You should create group before each and every VND string
2. Inside the group first you should check whether minus sign available or not so whe have : -?
3. the we need to capture every digits and we are expecting to have one or more : so [0-9]+
4. there might be a dot sign (zero or one) in case of decimal . so we have [.]+
5. again you might have another series  of digits after decimal ( zero or more) point so :  [0-9]*

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple regex

In Java

```
String regex = "(-?\\d*?\\.?\\d+)(?=VND)";
```

regex

```
(-?\d*?\.?\d+)(?=VND)
```

see [regex sample](https://regex101.com/r/HtgVEC/3)